# how to find the total numbers of hours of 2 dates in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

i have this table called records:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| date_returned       | date_borrowed       |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2013-05-31 09:27:38 | 2013-05-31 08:48:14 |
| 2013-05-31 09:22:27 | 2013-05-31 08:53:06 |
| 2013-05-31 09:27:38 | 2013-05-31 09:22:35 |
| 2013-05-31 15:27:02 | 2013-05-31 09:22:39 |
| 2013-05-31 15:27:02 | 2013-05-31 10:04:22 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

i want to include the total hours as another column in the result.
i read the manual but datediff seemed to be vague and just returns the difference as days.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT 
    TIMEDIFF(date_borrowed, date_returned) AS diff
FROM
    tablename
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    HOUR(TIMEDIFF(date_borrowed, date_returned)) as TotalHours
FROM
    tablename
```

Answer (score 2):

How about converting to timestamp values - that'll let you subtract to get the difference in seconds, and you can manipulate as much as you want from there.

```
SELECT
    date_returned,
    date_borrowed,
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_returned) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_borrowed)) / 3600 AS hours
FROM tablename
```